Does C standard define the calling convention?
Does the C standard define the calling convention? I find the calling convention cdecl stands for C declaration, but i can’t find anything about it in the C stardard draft.

No, this is compiler/OS/platform details. Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986844/what-does-cdecl-stand-for

Calling convention on wikipedia also has some info.

Calling conventions belongs to ABI.

Further reading As you read these paragraphs, bear in mind the distinction between the "abstract" language and the task of a compiler to emit code -- code that is specific for the target hardware/OS -- that fulfills (behaves) as portrayed in the well defined algorithm (program source code).

The C standard says:

The semantic descriptions in this International Standard describe the
behavior of an abstract machine

The behaviour of that abstract machine is described in 5.1.2 of the Standard
The calling convention is not there and it is left to the implementation.

No, the C standard does not specify calling conventions.
